# bind complex Class list to ListView in xaml page

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I have problem with binding complex list objects to listview's itemssource in xaml page.
Code is not writen in english so i will try to mock up my problem!
This is list which is used as itemssource

```
public ObservableCollection<Order> orderList { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Order>();
```

My Order  class has istance of OrderState class, and my OrderState class has instance of State class. 
State class has property named Name and this property I am trying to access so i could bind it to label in xaml page.

```
public class Order
{
    public virtual ICollection<OrderState> OrderState { get; set; }
   
}
```

```
public class OrderState
{
    public virtual ICollection<State> State { get; set; }
   
}
```

```
public partial class State
{
    public string Name{ get; set; }
}
```

So if i want to access Name property from Order class I need to go OrderState-> State-> name

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding orderList}"  >
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <StackLayout  Padding="10" Margin="5" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                           
                //dont know how to access Name property here          
                //I tried with OrderState.State.Name and State.Name but i only get empty text
                            <Label Text="{Binding Name}" 
                            d:Text="Item descripton"
                            LineBreakMode="NoWrap"
                            Style="{DynamicResource ListItemDetailTextStyle}"
                            FontSize="13" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
                            
                            
                        </StackLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>



        </ListView>
```

orderList has all data needed to display Name property, just dont know which path to use to get to it!
Any help is appreciated!!
Thank you for your time!
Main question solved , update question

```
var query = _context.Set<Database.Order>().AsQueryable();
 query = query.Include("OrderState").Include("OrderState.State");
```

how could i write this query so i can order OrderState by desc and take top 1 row???
Thank you for your time again!!!!!

Comment: `OrderState` and `State` are both collections of objects, so you must specify which element of the collection you're referencing, ie  `OrderState[0].State[0].Name`

Comment: Thanks for answering @Jason ! i solved it by using OrderState[0].State.Name ... I have one more question i will update main question!!!!

Comment: Try linq for sorting.

Comment: What property do you use for sorting? Is it the `Name` property of `State` Class?

Comment: if you have another question, please make another post